# Retrieve value from an column from sqlite database

Tags: android, database, sqlite, android-sqlite

I want something like below

My database contains a column called `Name` which contains following values

```
Name
a
a
b
b
a
c
b
d
```

I want to retrive something like below

```
Result
a
b
c
d
```

How can I achieve this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Distinct` is your friend

```
SELECT DISTINCT NAME FROM MYTABLE
```

http://www.sqlite.org/lang_select.html

Comment: or you can use GROUP_BY
SELECT NAME FROM TABLE_NAME GROUP_BY(NAME) ORDER BY NAME